# Find expected value of root of a sample variance

Tags: statistics, expectation

It is easy to compute $E(s^2)=E(\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2)=\sigma^2$.
My question is - how can E(s) be calculated?

I'm trying to use $\frac{s^2(n-1)}{\sigma^2}$ has Chi-square distribution, but it does not help a lot.